# Running socket connection in background in Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, sockets, push-notification

What is the best way to create a socket connection to receive messages for the user while the app is in the background?

This was possible prior to Android Oreo but now job scheduler is the only way to probably check whether messages have been received for the user. If so then how is WhatsApp able to function correctly in Android Oreo?

Comment: push notification as mentioned in the tag

Comment: by push notification, i hope u are not saying firebase, lets say i dont want use firebase at all, then how?

Comment: then what are you planning to use?

Comment: my point is google allows only firebase service to run in the background thats why it works but my company already has own push notification service which we want to use, how is that possible now running service in background for socket connection in android 8.1

Comment: WhatsApp is almost certainly using Firebase push notifications.  You could use your own with a foreground service, but that would be a huge battery drain.